# Button postback getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, postback

I have a updatepanel with a listview inside. This panel refreshes with an interval of 10 seconds, and listview source is updated and rebinded. My listview have some imagebuttons, and here comes the problem. When I click any of the listview buttons, I get a error:

> > "Invalid postback or callback argument." error.

I'm trying everything that I see on my serches, and no, I'll not set validation to false.

Here's a simplified template of my list.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlRegistro" ClientIDMode="Static" OnLoad="pnlRegistro_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvRegistro" OnPreRender="lvRegistro_PreRender" >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <!-- Unread notification count -->
                <span runat="server" id="spanRegistroCount" class="mws-dropdown-notif">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegistroCount" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                </span>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("RegistroHorarioId"))==0?"read":"unread"%>">
                    <a>
                        <div style="width: 80%; float: left;">
                            <span class="message" <%#Eval("SpanColor")%>>
                                <%#Eval("Status")%>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="float: right">
                            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnRegistro" OnClick="btnRegistro_Click"/>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What can I do to fix this error and fire **"btnRegistro_Click"** event?

Answer (score 0):

Update Panel is used for Updating Partial Page instead of doing full postback.

So,you have to add **PostBackTrigger** sync or async whatever you want because you are using update panel and for update panel events are defined in triggers to avoid full postback, so most probably you want asnc postback trigger.

add trigger for button event after content template end tag (`</ContentTemplate>`):

```
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers> 
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRegistro" EventName="Click" /> 
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

you should also read [**Understanding ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers**](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Comment: When I add this trigger, I get this error:

 "A control with ID 'btnRegistro' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'pnlRegistro'."

So I tried to use onItemCommand from ListView and add ItemCommand trigger, but I get

 "Invalid postback or callback argument." again.
 
Any ideas?

Comment: i have no idea of LIstView working but main reason of error is not adding trigger